# Как задать свой путь к dll-файлу?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

Программа зависит от двух dll-ок, и чтобы не пихать все вместе, я хочу положить их в папку dlls, например. Что нужно сделать, чтобы программа работала независимо от visual studio(то бишь, чтобы она могла запускаться на компьютере, на котором даже VS не стоит)

Comment: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)

Comment: Вы их загружаете динамически (LoadLibrary) или они грузятся статически?

Comment: Их .h файл подгружает